# While inside while loop works only the first time PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, while-loop

I did while inside while, but the second while working only in the first loop

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');

$output_name = md5(uniqid()) . ".csv";
$output = ROOT . "/uploads/output/" . $output_name;
$fp = fopen($output, 'wb');
fputcsv($fp, array('campaign', 'spent', 'payout', 'profit', 'roi'), ',');
$found_campaigns = [];

fgetcsv($file1); // Skip first line
while (($data = fgetcsv($file1)) !== FALSE) {
    array_push($found_campaigns, $data[$campaign]);
    echo $data[$campaign]; //  Runned propertly
    echo "</br>";


    // Check if the second file have same campgain name with the first file campgain name if yes take the payout field and merge them with the spent field.
    $found_in_file_2 = false;
    $pout = '';
    while (($data2 = fgetcsv($file2)) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Runned <br>"; // RUNNED ONCE.
        if ($data2[$campaign2] == $data[$campaign]) {
            $found_in_file_2 = true;
            $pout = $data2[$payout];
        }
    }

    $pout = str_replace('$', '', $pout);

    $line = [
        $data[$campaign],
        $data[$spent],
        $pout,
        $pout - $data[$spent],
        ($pout - $data[$spent]) / $data[$spent]
    ];

    fputcsv($fp, $line, ',');
}
```

The result is :

```
ZroJumiaNGMob1
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
ZroJumiaNGMob2
ZroJumiaNGMob3
ZroJumiaNGMob4
ZroJumiaNGMob5
ZroJumiaNGMob6
ZroJumiaNGMob7
ZroJumiaNGMob7
```

But the result need to be :

```
ZroJumiaNGMob1
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
ZroJumiaNGMob2
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob3
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob4
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob5
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob6
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob7
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
ZroJumiaNGMob7
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned 
Runned
```

actually its need to search the campgain name of data1 (not showen in the code) in the data 2 but i dident find a way to do this inside the while before its putting the line
I don't know why its not running in every loop in the while
Can someone help me with that

Comment: You did not include the calls to `fopen($file2)`, but the first time it reads to the end, it will not be rewound unless closed and reopened, or its cursor placed back at the beginning with `fseek($file2, 0)` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php

Comment: If the CSV files are not very large, you might consider loading the whole file into an array then using `foreach()` loops instead of reading the whole file from start to end on each iteration, which is slower.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski should i do this inside the second while ?

Comment: You do it in the first while, just before you start the second while.